# App to set as Launcher

Tags: android, launcher

**What i had done:** I have made a custom launcher that actually runs/sets as a home screen launcher upon load. Also it appears in the installed launchers list, which means everything is good so far.

**What i want:** But, when i launch/set my application as launcher and press back button, it goes to the previously set launcher screen.
It should not be like this i guess. It shall remain set like a home/default launcher of the device.

**My Code Additions:**
In my manifest i added following:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            <!-- These two lines are setting it as a launcher-->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any idea how i can achieve my goal ?

Comment: "It should not be like this i guess" -- yes, it should. Just because you are *now* the home screen does not change the fact that the old home screen is what started you, and therefore it is on the back stack. Your argument is akin to saying "I made this Web page be my browser's home page, so why does the BACK button take me back to the previous Web page?" "Any idea how i can achieve my goal ? " -- reboot.

Comment: @CommonsWare.. Most launchers are doing the same way.. I mean when they r started, and then if we press back button, then they are not going to the previous launcher screen.. They still remain on their own custom screen. That is what i want to create.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are certainly welcome to intercept the BACK button in your activity, by overriding `onBackPressed()`, and preventing it from destroying the activity by simply not chaining to the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Override the onKeyDown(), so that it doesn't do anything.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            //do nothing!
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Man.. Its simple comment the line "super.onBackPressed();" in the default onBackPressed method .. No scientific experiments like you are doing.. Do it simple !!